# Append n number of 0's as the prefix of integer

Tags: perl

I have the following data in a CSV file.

```
2454,"dum my"
12345,"dummy"
300001,"du m m y"
```

I was wondering, what regular expression I can use, to turn them into

```
002454,"dummy"
012345,"dummy"
300001,"dummy"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend reading and rewriting the CSV file with Text::CSV_XS and manipulating the fields individually, but if you must just use a regex, something like:

```
sub strip_spaces { my $str = shift; $str =~ y/ //d; $str }
s/(\d+)/ sprintf '%.6d', $1 /e;
s/("[^"]+"$)/ strip_spaces($1) /e;
```

Comment: May I know what is 'y' within strip_space? as I always saw 'm' and 's', but this is the first time I saw 'y'.

Comment: Legal link: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cds

Comment: @Sinan Sorry. I don't realize that was unauthorized copies. I remove it then :)

Comment: I once don't like Perl due to its difficult used symbol. Now I can appreciated it and understand why it is being called "Swiss Army chainsaw". I am able to solve my problem with just 12 lines of codes! Thanks.